# Extracting only json/dict from text OR Getting text inside matched parenthesis

Tags: json, python-3.x, text-parsing, text-processing

I am trying to get only part of json from big text file which can contain all kind of text..

I approached to problem by trying to match/get all text between parenthesis `{}`, but still I trust there should be better way to do it, so please give me some proposal. Maybe to split file and than to try to parse it, or is there some library I am missing? This I have to perform on files bigger than 200MB.

```
citaj="""
..bla....bla....bla...bla....bla....
supportedBandCombination-r10{
  BandCombinationParameters-r10{
    BandParameters-r10{
      bandEUTRA-r101,
      bandParametersUL-r10{
        CA-MIMO-ParametersUL-r10{
          ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10a
        }
      },
      bandParametersDL-r10{
        CA-MIMO-ParametersDL-r10{
          ca-BandwidthClassDL-r10a,
          supportedMIMO-CapabilityDL-r10twoLayers
        }
      }
    }
  },
  BandCombinationParameters-r10{
    BandParameters-r10{
      bandEUTRA-r103,
      bandParametersUL-r10{
        CA-MIMO-ParametersUL-r10{
          ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10a
        }
      },
      bandParametersDL-r10{
        CA-MIMO-ParametersDL-r10{
          ca-BandwidthClassDL-r10a,
          supportedMIMO-CapabilityDL-r10twoLayers
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
..bla....bla....bla...bla....bla....
..bla....bla....bla...bla....bla...."""


import re
string = open("citaj.txt","r").read()
stack = 0
startIndex = None
results = []
indx = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('BandCombinationParameters', string)]
for jota in indx:
    for i, c in enumerate(string[jota:]):  
        if c == '{':
            if stack == 0:
                startIndex = i + 1 # string to extract starts one index later
            # push to stack
            stack += 1
        elif c == '}':
            # pop stack
            stack -= 1

            if stack == 0:
                results.append(string[startIndex:i])
print(results)
```

Output should be

```
results[0]=
BandCombinationParameters-r10{
  BandParameters-r10{
    bandEUTRA-r101,
    bandParametersUL-r10{
      CA-MIMO-ParametersUL-r10{
        ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10a
      }
    },
    bandParametersDL-r10{
      CA-MIMO-ParametersDL-r10{
        ca-BandwidthClassDL-r10a,
        supportedMIMO-CapabilityDL-r10twoLayers
      }
    }
  }
}
results[1]=
BandCombinationParameters-r10{
  BandParameters-r10{
    bandEUTRA-r103,
    bandParametersUL-r10{
      CA-MIMO-ParametersUL-r10{
        ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10a
      }
    },
    bandParametersDL-r10{
      CA-MIMO-ParametersDL-r10{
        ca-BandwidthClassDL-r10a,
        supportedMIMO-CapabilityDL-r10twoLayers
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Python, you may find pyparsing a quick way to prototype up a parser for this format (which is not JSON, btw):

```
src = """
supportedBandCombination-r10{
  BandCombinationParameters-r10{
    BandParameters-r10{
      bandEUTRA-r101,
      bandParametersUL-r10{
        CA-MIMO-ParametersUL-r10{
          ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10a
        }
      },
      bandParametersDL-r10{
        CA-MIMO-ParametersDL-r10{
          ca-BandwidthClassDL-r10a,
          supportedMIMO-CapabilityDL-r10twoLayers
        }
      }
    }
  },
  BandCombinationParameters-r10{
    BandParameters-r10{
      bandEUTRA-r103,
      bandParametersUL-r10{
        CA-MIMO-ParametersUL-r10{
          ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10a
        }
      },
      bandParametersDL-r10{
        CA-MIMO-ParametersDL-r10{
          ca-BandwidthClassDL-r10a,
          supportedMIMO-CapabilityDL-r10twoLayers
        }
      }
    }
  }
}"""

import pyparsing as pp

LBRACE,RBRACE = map(pp.Suppress, "{}")
term = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums+'-')

term_group = pp.Forward()
term_group <<= pp.Group(term + pp.Group(LBRACE 
                                         + pp.delimitedList(term_group | term) 
                                         + RBRACE))

term_group.parseString(src).pprint()
```

Prints

```
[['supportedBandCombination-r10',
  [['BandCombinationParameters-r10',
    [['BandParameters-r10',
      ['bandEUTRA-r101',
       ['bandParametersUL-r10',
        [['CA-MIMO-ParametersUL-r10', ['ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10a']]]],
       ['bandParametersDL-r10',
        [['CA-MIMO-ParametersDL-r10',
          ['ca-BandwidthClassDL-r10a',
           'supportedMIMO-CapabilityDL-r10twoLayers']]]]]]]],
   ['BandCombinationParameters-r10',
    [['BandParameters-r10',
      ['bandEUTRA-r103',
       ['bandParametersUL-r10',
        [['CA-MIMO-ParametersUL-r10', ['ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10a']]]],
       ['bandParametersDL-r10',
        [['CA-MIMO-ParametersDL-r10',
          ['ca-BandwidthClassDL-r10a',
           'supportedMIMO-CapabilityDL-r10twoLayers']]]]]]]]]]]
```

BUT, pyparsing is *not* fast, and will take quite a while to sift through your 200MB file.

Pyparsing also is not good about streaming, but will want to parse an entire string at once. This may or may not be practical with your 200MB file. What you could do is try to read a line at a time until you get a parseable structure, then parse it and move on. Or read 100 lines at a time until you get a parseable structure, then parse it, keep the unparsed part, and then get another 100 lines. But in all this, the performance limiter will be the parser, so you'll want to minimize the number of bad parses while trying to build up a successfully parseable string.